# addTextChangedListener cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm having an error trying to create an app that allows for textboxes to be added and taken away from a screen. The error that I am having involves the addTextChangedListener method as Android Studio is saying that it cannot resolve the method. I know that this method must be placed within the onCreate method but am unsure how to alter my code to achieve this. Any help would be really great. My main code is as follows.

```
package com.example.a11111111.gamesaid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Parent view for the main screen
    private LinearLayout layoutView;

    //Add Button
    private Button addButton;

    //One empty row must always be present
    private View emptyView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        layoutView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);


    }

    //create on click handler for the add button

    public void addNew(View v)
    {
        addRow(null, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //Add delete handler

    public void deleteRow(View v)
    {
        layoutView.removeView((View) v.getParent());
    }

    public void addRow(String name, int score) {

        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View row = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        final Button delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        final EditText editName = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText editScore = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.score);


        //if a value is entered in both fields, add it to the activity
        //else delete the row
        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty() && score != 0 )
        {
            editName.setText(name);
            editScore.setText(score);
        } else

        {
            emptyView = row;
            delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        //add a textWatcher to control visibility of Add button and empty view

        name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable i) {
                 if (i.toString().isEmpty()) {
                     addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                     if (emptyView != null && emptyView != row) {
                         layoutView.removeView(emptyView);
                     }
                     emptyView = row;
                 } else {
                     if (emptyView == row) {
                         emptyView = null;
                     }

                     addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)

             {
             }

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count)
             {
             }
        });

        layoutView.addView(row, layoutView.getChildCount()- 1);


    }










    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `name` is of type `String`. `String` doesn't have a `addTextChangedListener()` method.

I suppose you should add the listener to one of your edit text, most probably `editName`.